# How can my rails app provide SSO for another java application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on

I have a Rails application that I want to be the "master" application in terms of uses authentication.

So a user first logs into my Rails application

www.example.com

When they go to the other application (which is java)

www.example2.com

I want them to be authenticated based on them already logging into the Rails application.

From what I understand all of these oauth gems are for connecting to things like twitter, facebook etc. where twitter/facebook is the master login site.

What libraries do I need to make my own website the "master" login?

Comment: You can use Oauth (there are plenty of tutorials if you google) or use SAML 2.0 protocol to provide identity. Java supports it very well. Here is a rails provider https://github.com/lawrencepit/ruby-saml-idp

Comment: @LucasM I need more details on the different parts.  Confused between oauth provder and consumer etc.